# Can you use a piece of paper to test the seal of a bore?

Tags: engine, testing

I was watching a YouTube video the other day and in it you see a middle aged man and a younger man next to him. They're working on an engine, the younger man cranking the shaft, and the older man is testing the seal of the bores. He does this by using a damp piece of paper, and tells the younger guy to turn the crank. The younger one does so and the piston moves up and makes the paper pop. He does this four more times (twice on the last bore, because it doesn't pop the paper), and says it's good.

So, I was wondering if this is a cheaper way to check if there is no leaks between the piston and the walls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think this in any way an accurate test of anything useful.  Even a relatively bad "seal", and I suspect you mean the piston ring seal here, will have enough compression to "pop" a piece of wet paper.

The correct way is to make sure that your rings are installed properly and that the cylinder bore is within specs.  Also check that the ring end-gap is within specs.

Comment: I believe this is the video I was talking about it. - https://www.youtube.com/shorts/hxDsGFmpuWY

Comment: Watching that just confirms my belief that this is "snake oil" and not sound measurement.  Use this method at your own risk.